# Copy Pasting Opened Sheet File to Current Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I was just finished automating my report (open ie, navigate ie, extract data, and open downloaded data). I'm now in the process of copy pasting the extracted file to the current workbook. The issues are the

- downloaded workbook have different numbers at the end of its name
  every
- download first tab or sheet is not named "Sheet 1

After the last sendKey command, the downloaded file will open.

Every file has one name identifier which is "RealTime" For the file name and tab.

Commented scripts are not working

```
Sub Get_RawFile()
'
'
'
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLselect As HTMLSelectElement

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("-------------------------")

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = Sheets("Data Dump").Range("A1").Value
    HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B1").Value
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("login-btn").Click

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    Set objButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("s2id_ddlReportType")
    Set HTMLselect = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlReportType")
    objButton.Focus
    HTMLselect.Value = "2"

    Set HTMLselectZone = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlTimezone")
    HTMLselectZone.Value = "PST8PDT"

    Set subgroups = HTMLDoc.getElementById("s2id_ddlSubgroups")
    subgroups.Click
    Set subgroups2 = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlSubgroups")
    subgroups2.Value = "1456_17"

    HTMLDoc.getElementById("dtStartDate").Value = Format(Sheets("Attendance").Range("B6").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("dtEndDate").Value = Format(Sheets("Attendance").Range("X6").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnGetReport").Focus
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnGetReport").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnDowloadReport").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Application.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
        If Left(wB.Name, 14) = "RealTime" Then
           Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook
           Exit For
       End If
    Next

    'If Not Wb1 Is Nothing Then
    '    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

    '   With Wb1.Sheets(1)
    '        Set rngToCopy = .Range("A:U", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    '    End With
    '   wb2.Sheets(2).Range("A5").Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value
    'End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You are using thisworkbook everytime. Should be different books. One that is found and other the workbook you want to copy data into.

**Change the Part After SendKeys with:**

```
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
Dim rngToCopy As Range

Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook

For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(wB.Name, 14) = "RealTime" Then
       Set wb2 = wB
       Exit For
   End If
Next

If Not wb2 Is Nothing Then

    With wb2.Sheets(1)
        Set rngToCopy = .Range("A1:U", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
    End With

    Wb1.Sheets(2).Range("A5").Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value

End If
```

Comment: Hello Mikku. This line of code `With wb2.Sheets(1)
        Set rngToCopy = .Range("A:U", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    Wb1.Sheets(2).Range("A5").Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value` does not work at all. It doesn't even highlight the range I want to copy. It seems that it's being ignored as per code `If Not wb2 Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change the line `Set wb2 = wB`, now I did. Try again

Comment: I changed the code and it now debugs at `Wb1.Sheets(2).Range("A5").Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value` _Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object defined error_. It also shows that the `.Range("A:U", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))` is not being highlighted to copy.

Comment: Yes, there are other issues in your code rather than the ones mentioned in Question. Anyways, i have tried to fix this one also. Run the answer again

Comment: Hi Mikku. I was able to run the copy paste code now. Using this code `With wb2.Sheets(1)
        Set rngToCopy = .Range("A1:U50", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        rngToCopy.Copy
    End With
    
    For Each wb2 In Application.Workbooks
        wb2.Activate
    Next
    
    Wb1.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("A6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`
However it only runs in debug mode. It seems I'm missing a few codes after the send keys(Last send key function opens the downloaded file) so that it will follow up with that action. Can you help me?

Comment: Probably you should ask a new question for that. :) All the best with your code.

Comment: I actually did. Lol. No one has replied yet. Thanks btw!